# Parsing first line of csv and creating a table inside database

Tags: php, mysql

I am downloading new csv's each night using a cron job with PHP. Each csv is normally about the same, possibly one night within a month a field is new. I need to get the new field and append it to the database. I don't know how to get the type of the new field. I saw someone else's question with gettype() but i'm not sure if that would work or not since the data is inside a csv so wouldn't they all be strings when some need to be floats, or ints? How would I go across checking the type?

The second question, is there a way to check if there is not a name inside of a table? For instance, if they add a new field called foo52, and I have foo1 through foo51 in my database, is there a quick way to search for fields that aren't there, or would I have to use a select statement for each one and append it when it's false?

I use MySQL for my database.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: csv files have no "type". they're just strings of data separated by commas (or some other character). It's up to you to decide if `12345` is an integer or a string that happens to look like an integer. In other words, if you aren't told what the new field's type is, you'll have to fall back on using a text/varchar field to hold it.

Comment: That's what I thought, does it really matter if I just store all the information inside the database as Text?

Comment: no, not for just storing. but later on if you're going to be actually USING that data within the db, it'd be better to convert that new field to an appropriate type. Easier to simply slurp in all the new field data, then pick through it within the db to decide if it's text, numeric, etc...

Comment: Well it's going to be displayed on my site, which is the main reason I don't want to use Text for each field. The average csv contains about 10,000 - 30,000 rows which need to be inserted.

Comment: Then you'd have to read through the csv first, figure out what the field's type is, create the appropriate db field, THEN slurp in the data. it'd be no use to create an int field, then find out there's some text in a row way down the line.

Comment: Well they don't change it, i'm not the only one. if it's an int, it's going to stay an int. Is there a simple method on getting the type of a field?

Comment: since you're the one building the csv, then if the first row has the new field as  an int, then just create an int field. if it's text, create a text field, etc...

Comment: I just download a new one each night. I have to read and update my database with the new information inside of it.

Comment: so... read the first line of the csv, check if there's a new field and it's text/int/whatever, modify your DB if/as needed, then start inserting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question on the part about getting the type is the simply try the conversion of the data itself and then seeing if the data is equivalent with a `==` comparison.

So,

```
some,data,is,123
```

After reading in the data you can then try the conversion to various types such as strings, ints, ect...then from that you are able to determine the type of the data.

For the second question you can get the column names by doing:

```
show columns from db.table_name
```

Then you can do a simple `in_array` to test if the new column name is already in the database.

EDIT:

Using `array_diff` can simplify the finding of the missing/new column names from the CSV.

```
csv_names = get_csv_column_names();
sql_names = get_sql_column_names();

new_names = array_diff( csv_names, sql_names );
```

Comment: Would I have to have a for loop and do the `in_array` check for each column name in the csv?

Comment: What you can do is read in the column names from the top of the CSV into an array and then get the column names from the DB and use `array_diff` to find the differing column names.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [parsecsv-for-php](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/) library very handy for [re|de]constructing CSV data.

Comment: That link might help someone else, but I prefer the [fgetcsv](http://md.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) method. I just need to know how to get the type, if it really matters. And an answer to my second question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: you can test if it's numeric with is_numeric(). If not, store as string. If yes, create the field as numeric in your database. If you want, you can use regex to check if it's a date or some other datatype you think is required to be stored correctly (i.e. not a a default-text)

for the second question: getting the fieldnames of a table in Postgres is done with the follwoing query

```
$sql = "SELECT attname FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                    WHERE attrelid =
                        (SELECT c.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n  ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
                            WHERE c.relname = '$this->tableName' AND n.nspname = 'public')
                        AND attnum > 0
                        AND NOT attisdropped";
```

For MySQL, it should be doable with "show columns from db.table_name".

Once you have the fields, use in_array() to check if it exists already...

Note that: you'd probably need to check for all columns in your CSV if they exist already. If not: add a new colum for it. If yes, leave it as is...

Comment: what if the first few rows are numeric, and then it changes to text somewhere farther into the .csv?

Comment: Marc B: it all depends on what you know about the CSV file of course. But it's easy enough to a) check what fieldtype you have, b) before inserting or updating, check if all fieldtypes match c) if not, alter table and change fieldtype to text.

Comment: You should create the table after you have read the data, if at all possible, and if the data type switches then just pick a string based data type as that can store any data that is stored in a CSV.